# Namefile does not exist for MF/MT3DMS/SEAWAT model

Tags: python, flopy

I build a coupled MODFLOW-MT3DMS-SEAWAT model. Similar to [this example](https://www.hatarilabs.com/ih-en/basic-example-of-saline-intrusion-modeling-seawat-and-flopy) according to the packages and executable swt_v4 (of course I use a lot more input variables).

However when I try to run the model I get the following error:

```
FloPy is using the following  executable to run the model: /usr/bin/swt_v4
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-202-77d16ae8d2d8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/Dylan/Desktop/model_0705_swt.py', wdir='/Users/Dylan/Desktop')

  File "/Users/Dylan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/Dylan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/Dylan/Desktop/model_0705_swt.py", line 388, in <module>
    swt.run_model()

  File "/Users/Dylan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flopy/mbase.py", line 970, in run_model
    normal_msg=normal_msg)

  File "/Users/Dylan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flopy/mbase.py", line 1387, in run_model
    raise Exception(s)

Exception: The namefile for this model does not exists: swt_model_0605.nam
```

If I run the command `print(swt.namfile)` it is normally prompted as `swt_model_0605.nam`

I use the following packages: DIS, BAS, LPF, PCG, OC, GHB, WEL, ADV, BTN, DSP, GCG, SSM & VDF.

Is there a way how to track down this error?

Comment: A common reason I've encountered for this error is that the model workspace has not been set properly so that when flopy runs the model it's looking in the wrong directory for the namefile.